# how to change color code of header and footer in m2

Tags: css, frontend

[image]hi, 
   i am new to magento would some one please help me to set this in a right way

i just have change the background color of header and footer of my magento store 
in the base directory within the tag .page-header .panel.wrapper  path:"https://cartify.shop/pub/static/version1486689053/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css" it has been saved correctly and showing in the coding but the frontend didn't show any changes at my home page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to add styling to a magento 2 store is to add your code here:

ADMIN > CONTENT > Design > CONFIGURATION

Click Edit for the appropriate view (global, website or store)

Open tab HTML Head, under Scripts and Style Sheets, you can add the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media (min-width: 768px), print {
 .page-header .panel.wrapper {
  background-color: #fff
 }
 .copyright {
  background-color: #f00
 }
}
</style>
```

Click Save Configuration

Clear Cache

Comment: please also give the method to change the background color of footer copyright area

Comment: Added the copyright as well.

Comment: its just vanished all the content in my site, displaying nothing

Comment: my mistake, sorry for that, All changes have done seamlessly, thanks a lot